# OAuth in Spring security question to get userInfo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

My application has frontend build with angular and backend build with spring boot, and I use openam by Forgerock as an authentication server. I got the access_token in frontend and pass this access_token to backend through Bearer authentication, But now I have to check if the token is valid in backend by calling /userInfo endpoint. My question is how to config in spring boot to call this endpoint everytime when get the request? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may case I didn't had any explicit configuration for access token. You just have to call end points and the tokens will be stored in the header for authentication. Though you can set the timer for it.

Comment: To get the token at first place I send the post request containing username and password.